# In memory web index

Tags: php, caching, memory, indexing, disk

[Quoting wikipedia:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_platform)

> The index is very large due to the number of documents stored in the servers.[17]
>   ...
>    and in early 2001 Google switched to an in-memory index system.

Well, Google has over 40 bn pages in their index, and [here's the proof...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_search_engines)

So how does Google get the huge index to memory.. I know that reading from disk is slower than reading for memory and hence, google storing index in memory makes it fast..

I am making a search engine where i have the index in a `.db` file... i have memcache installed for PHP so i thought of putting up the whole index on the cache.. But does the cache (PHP Memcache) have the capability of storing objects as big as the web index??

Help needed, languages: C(++), Python, PHP...

Comment: Google is using [1000 machines for a single query](http://www.labnol.org/internet/search/google-query-uses-1000-machines/7433/). So you can't compare that with a single server setup :)

Comment: but still they're storing the index in memory right? assuming that i have a 1000 machines to store my index, how do i take it to the memory? @Rik

Comment: Google has over 900.000 servers (in 2011 maybe more now) (not 1000). See [here](http://www.datacenterknowledge.com/archives/2011/08/01/report-google-uses-about-900000-servers/) and [here](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2011/08/01/google_server_count/) Only a "small" portion (1000) is used **per query**. I don't know what is involved in spreading this over all the machines but i'm sure not all machines (not even 1000 of them) have the complete web-index in memory. (perhaps Google's best kept secret)

Comment: Not an answer but for some light reading: [The Anatomy of a Large-Scale Hypertextual Web Search Engine](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~backrub/google.html).